# Como contar los terminos en un archivo txt

Tags: python, txt

```
T = ['.', ',', '-', 'hola', 'soy', 'Alexander']
simbolos = ['.', ',', '-']
texto = []

while len(texto) < 73:
    if len(texto) == 0:
        pal1 = random.choice(T)
        if pal1 not in simbolos:
            texto.append(pal1)
    else:
        sgt_pal = random.choice(T)
        if texto[-1] in simbolos and sgt_pal not in simbolos:
            if texto[-1] == ',':
                texto.append(' ' + sgt_pal)
            elif texto[-1] == '.':
                texto.append('\n' + sgt_pal)
            else:
                texto.append(sgt_pal)
        elif texto[-1] not in simbolos and sgt_pal not in simbolos:
            texto.append(' ' + sgt_pal)
        elif texto[-1] not in simbolos and sgt_pal in simbolos:
            texto.append(sgt_pal)
        else:
            pass

with open('literatura.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(texto)
```

Este es el código del programa,necesito asegurarme de que hayan 73 términos, incluyendo los simbolos y excluyendo los espacios, pero no se como hacer para separar todo sin decir específicamente en que palabras y simbolos quiero que se separe.

Comment: Por concretar: ¿es un código que quieres mejorar o es un código que genera un fichero ejemplo para procesar?

Comment: @ChemaCortes me decia que tengo una lista con una cantidad de terminos indefinidos y tenia escoger aleatoriamente de ella para hacer un archivo con una extension de 73 terminos. Las condiciones que me pedian ya estan cumplidas en ese codigo, ahora solo necesito asegurarme de que tiene los 73 terminos (entre palabras y simbolos).

Comment: Estaría bien que hubieras puesto un ejemplo concreto de la salida para comprobar las soluciones.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, tienes un texto generado automáticamente según unos criterios y quieres comprobar si hay 73 términos de una lista dada.

Podemos suponer que los términos estará separados por los siguientes separadores:

```
sep = [' ', ', ', '.\n']
```

La idea es dividir el texto en sus términos y contabilizarlos, algo que se hace muy bien con expresiones regulares:

```py
import re


sep = [' ', ', ', '.\n']  # separadores
pat = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(sep)})")  # patrón para separar téminos

texto = open('literatura.txt').read()  # lectura del fichero a chequear

num_terms = sum(1 for x in pat.split(texto) if x not in [' '])
```

Lo más complicado es ver cómo se crea el patrón. La expresión `'|'.join(sep)` es una concatenación de los separadores separados por `'|'`, algo así: `'( |, |.\n)'`

Esta concatenación se usa como expresión regular para dividir el texto en términos. Algo así:

```
['soy',
 ', ',
 'soy',
 ' ',
 'soy',
 '.\n',
 'Alexander',
 ' ',
 'Alexander',
 ' ',
 'soy',
  ...
```

En el *split* aparecen tanto los términos como los separadores. Al contabilizar términos, quitamos los que son espacios en blanco, algo que se logra con esta expresión:

```py
num_terms = sum(1 for x in pat.split(texto) if x not in [' '])
```

---

**Edición**: sólo por comparar, así es como hubiera hecho yo la generación de los 73 términos, separando claramente la obtención de los 73 términos del texto resultante:

```py
import random
from itertools import islice

T = ['.', ',', '-', 'hola', 'soy', 'Alexander']
simbolos = ['.', ',', '-']

# cadena infinita de términos
def terminos():

    want_symbols = False

    while True:
        t = random.choice(T)
        if want_symbols or t not in simbolos:
            yield t
        want_symbols = t not in simbolos

# tomamos los 73 primeros
toma = list(islice(terminos(), 73))

#sustitución de símbolos
subs = { '.': '.\n', '-': '-', ',': ', '}

texto = ""
prev = True  # ¿el anterior es símbolo?
for x in toma:
    texto += subs.get(x, (' '+x) if not prev else x)
    prev = x in subs

print(texto)
```